# For $f$ harmonic on the unit disk, $\lvert\nabla f(0)\rvert \leqslant 2 \sup|f|$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, harmonic-functions

> Let $f(x,y)$ be a harmonic function on the unit disk, such that $|f| \leqslant M$. Prove that $\lvert\nabla f(0)\rvert \leq 2M$ using the formula 
>   $$f(z)=\frac 1 {2\pi}\int _0^{2 \pi} f(e^{i \phi})P_r(\theta-\phi)d\phi$$

Here $P_r(\theta) =\frac{1-|z|^2}{|1-z|^2} =  \frac{1-r^2}{1+r^2-2r \cos \theta}$.

Differentiating the formula yields 
$$\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial x}=\frac 1 {2\pi}\int _0^{2 \pi} f(e^{i \phi}) 
\frac{\partial  P_r(\theta-\phi)}{dx}d\phi$$

$$|\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial x}| \leqslant \frac M {2\pi}\int _0^{2 \pi} |
\frac{\partial  P_r(\theta-\phi)}{dx}|d\phi$$

and similarly for $y$, so

$$|\nabla f(z)|=|\frac 1 {2\pi}\int _0^{2 \pi} f(e^{i \phi}) 
\nabla P_r(\theta-\phi)d\phi| \leqslant \frac M {2\pi} |\int _0^{2 \pi} \nabla P_r(\theta-\phi)d\phi|$$$$ \leqslant\frac M {2\pi} \int _0^{2 \pi} |\nabla P_r(\theta-\phi)|d\phi$$
but the two explicit derivatives inside the gradient in the integral are complicated and do not seem to be bounded by $\frac 12$, which would have allowed the estimation $|\nabla f(0)| \leq |f_x(0)|+|f_y(0)| \leq 2M$.

To compute the gradient I think we may differentiate as a complex function and then substitute $ze^{-i \phi}$: 
$$\nabla P = \nabla \text{Re} (\frac{1+z}{1-z})=\text{Re}(\frac d {dz}\frac{1+z}{1-z})=\text{Re}(\frac {2}{(1-z)^2})$$

So for $\phi=0, z=0$ we are not bounded by 1, and so pointwise estimates are not enough. How can I proceed, then?

Comment: You mean $|\nabla f(0)|$ in your question? (And in the title of the question you need something like: "An upper bound on the magnitude of the gradient of a harmonic function"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we use normalized arc length measure on the circle, we can write the Poisson kernel as

$$P(z,\zeta) = \frac{1-|z|^2}{|z-\zeta|^2} = (1-|z|^2)(|z-\zeta|^2)^{-1}$$

for $|z|<1, |\zeta|=1.$ Then, with $\zeta = (\zeta_1, \zeta_2),$ we have

$$ \frac{\partial P(z,\zeta)}{\partial x} = -2x(|z-\zeta| ^2)^{-1}+ (1-|z|^2)(-1)(|z-\zeta|^2)^{-2}\cdot 2(x- \zeta_1).$$

At $z=0$ this equals $2\zeta_1.$ Thus

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} 2\cos t \cdot u(t)\, dt.$$

In absolute value this is no more than $\dfrac{4M}{\pi}.$ The estimate for $|\partial u/\partial y(0)|$ is the same. Therefore $|\nabla u (0)| \le \sqrt 2\dfrac{4M}{\pi}.$ Since $\sqrt 2\dfrac{4}{\pi} <2$ by a bit, we're done.

Comment: Thanks. For future reference, I'll note that $P_r(\theta-\phi)=\frac{1-|z|^2}{|e^{i \phi}-z|^2}$, so we define $\zeta = e^{i \phi}$. The derivative I get is a little different (Why $|z-\zeta^2|$ there?), but the same result $2\zeta_1$.

Comment: $\zeta^2$ was a typo, now fixed